# Element id in the loop (JSOUP)

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my code:

```
   Element current = doc.select("tr[class=row]").get(5);   
   for (Element td : current.children()) {
          System.out.println(td.text());
   }
```

How can I get an Element id in the loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In HTML `id` is a normal attribute, so you can simply call `td.attr("id")`:

```
Element current = doc.select("tr.row").get(5);
for (Element td : current.children()) {
    System.out.println(td.attr("id"));
}
```

Note that there is also a selector for classes: `tr.row`.

JSoup supports many of the CSS selectors, so this could be rewritten with a single selector:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("tr.row:nth-of-type(6) > td");

for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.id());
}
```